# How to use Google API to find 'duration' with using Lat and Lon

Tags: url, google-maps-api-3

I tried Google API using example bellow: `https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?origin=75+9th+Ave+New+York,+NY&destination=MetLife+Stadium+1+MetLife+Stadium+Dr+East+Rutherford,+NJ+07073&departure_time=1541202457&traffic_model=best_guess`

It works fine but need to do the same example using Lat and Lon instead of real Address for Start and End.
What is the example of doing the same like above but using Lat and Lon?

Thanks.

Comment: Don't the API references provide options for that? I believe they do support geo coordinates.

Comment: Just tried with finding exact coordinates for Lat and Lon (apparently I was testing with not correct Lat and Lon which was returning errors from google). This is working : https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?
origin=40.741963,-74.004915&
destination=40.812840,-74.074209&
departure_time=1541202457&
traffic_model=best_guess

Answer (score 0):

Apparently I was testing at first with not correct Lat and Lon which was returning errors from google. This is working:

```
https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/json?
origin=40.741963,-74.004915&
destination=40.812840,-74.074209&
departure_time=1541202457&
traffic_model=best_guess
```